Brakes Locking Up
2002 Honda Accord when you take off and reach around 10 mph the brakes lock up and bring you to a stop. The brakes will release after a few seconds or you can put it in reverse and they will release.

Were these brakes serviced recently?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
